# Extract informations with php preg_match_all

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all, trim

I'm trying to modify a script to extract informations:

There are pages with for example:

```
<ul class="tags">
<li><div class="tag"><a href="http://www.url1.com" title="url1">title 1</a></div></li>
<li><div class="tag"><a href="http://www.url2.com" title="url2">title 2</a></div></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to get title 1,title 2

I have this code:

```
$m=array();
preg_match_all("/<a href="(.*)" title="(.*)">(.*)<\/a>/i", $buff,$m);
$info['tags']=trim(strip_tags($m[3]));
$cats=array_map('trim',$cats);
$info['tags']=implode(',',$cats);
```

But i get errors with trim and array_map.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: i suggest use an HTML parser for this, `DOMDocument` in particular

Answer (score 0):

The first error in your code is in the 3rd line:

```
$info['tags']=trim(strip_tags($m[3]));
```

Here for function `strip_tags` should be given string as argument, but `$m[3]` is array. A quick fix would be:

```
$info['tags']=array_map('strip_tags',array_map('trim',$m[3]));
```

$info[tags] is now:

```
[tags] => Array
   (
       [0] => title 1
       [1] => title 2
   )
```

Than apply implode function so:

```
$info['tags'] = implode(',', $info['tags']);
```

Cheers, Bea

Comment: i want $info[tags] to be title 1,title 2

Comment: in that case you can use the implode function so : $info[tags] = implode(",", $info[tags]), and the result will be title 1, title2